# Updating view A that was behind view B after the back button in the navigation bar is pressed and view B is popped

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

I have two views A & B in order to go from A to B I'm just pushing the new view, in view B I preform some actions that update the badgeValue of a UIBarButton item of my navigation bar. (Like adding an item to the shopping cart)

[image: picture 30]

When I go back to view A using the navigationBar Back button the UIBarButton item shows the previous badgeValue, instead of the updated one, I guess this happens because when you press the back button view B is popped revealing view A which is left as it was without any changes so, I need a way to tell view A to update itself after returning.

[image: picture 29]

If instead of going back to view A I go back to the rootViewController the badgeValue is updated, I guess that when I go to the rootViewController the code in viewDidLoad is read and the badgeValue is updated.

Any ideas on how to update a view that was behind another that was just popped?

**EDIT**

@silicon_valley answer is correct but it won't work with MikeMTOL's library because it's buggy, for Swift users I'd recommend these extensions instead. -> [link](https://gist.github.com/yonat/75a0f432d791165b1fd6)

Comment: Look up a tutorial on using an unwind segue.  This will let you pass data back to the previous ViewController and update the badge.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks, I'll check that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your code to update the badge value in `viewWillAppear`. That will make sure the value is updated every time the view will come back on the screen (and not just the first time it is created).

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but what this does is that it disappears the badgeValue completely.

I'm currently updating the badgeValue in the viewDidLayoutSubViews() method: 

 `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        var numeroProducto = String(Carrito.numProd)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.badgeValue = numeroProducto
    }`

that's the only way I can keep it when pushing to another viewController because if I put it in viewDidLoad it disappears after the new controller is pushed.

Comment: So how/where are you creating the `UIBarButtonItem`? The behavior you describe seems odd...

Comment: I'm not creating it, it's just the standard back button arrow that the navigation bar has, the only thing I did was change it's default icon for a custom one and I'm using a single navigation controller for all the views after the login view. I'm using the standard back button because I don't want to create a button for all my views and have to use a selector for each in order to perform the back function, which also "pops" the viewcontroller on top.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The `rightBarButtonItem` seems like a custom `UIBarButtonItem` if it's got a property called `badgeValue`? I don't mean the back button but the button with the shopping cart icon. Or are they the same?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were talking about the back button. 

The `rightBarButtonItem` is being created with the Interfase Builder but I'm using a library called `UIBarButtonItem + Badge` - [link](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge),  it basically expands the functionality of the `BarButtons` or `UIButtons` with the ability to put a `badgeValue` in them like this `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.badgeValue = "1"`
I'm saving an array of items and then I load them back when the app starts I get the badgeValue using the array.count

Comment: Very strange. I've just created my own view controller which works fine:
`class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        if let rightbbi = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
            rightbbi.badgeValue = "\(arc4random_uniform(20))"
        } else {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .search, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Ok, now try this, in your first viewcontroller assign any value (not random or it won't work) create another viewcontroller and in that viewcontroller add +1 to your badgeValue, then press the back button on the navigation bar
you'll get back to view A and the badgeValue that you'll have will be the previous one, not the updated value with +1 I found a fork of that class - [link](https://github.com/MobileXLabs/UIBarButtonItem-Badge/),  I hope this one works better for me but you need to install the KVOController libraries to use it, I'm downloading them and i'll let you know.

Comment: Okay, yes, now I have the same problem. It looks like a bug in the UIBarButtonItem+Badge code.

Comment: I Finally solved it! The solution above works but you need to change MikeMTOL's UIBarButtonItems+Badge for another library because it has a bug that prevents you to update the badge value in `viewWillAppear` 

The solution provided above + this gist -> [link](https://gist.github.com/yonat/75a0f432d791165b1fd6) worked like a charm for me it's a bit more complicated to setup a button vs MikeMTOL's but this one works well, and I searched and searched for badgeValue classes or frameworks and the one of the link above provided to be the best.